# Application wide styles file for WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to have a file called `Styles.xaml` which will contain a number of different styles for my current project. I would like all styles in this file to be easily accessible to every control in the project.

Here is what the project looks like so far:

`Styles.xaml`:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="TestStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <!-- Style properties here -->
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

`App.xaml`:

```
<Application x:Class="ProjectName.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProjectName"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- Application wide configurations here -->
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

`CustomControl.xaml`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ProjectName.Controls.CustomControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Background="White"
             d:MinHeight="24" d:MinWidth="100" >
    <Grid>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource TestStyle}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I get the following error in design view: `'TestSyle' resource not found`.

How do I correctly setup the project and/or reference the style so that it can be used in the control?

Comment: If you want to just inherit *implicit* styles automatically you can just put them in App.xaml.  but if you want to explicitly refer to styles by name as `StaticResource` in your `UserControl` I'm pretty sure that control is going to need to see the XAML where they are defined.

Comment: My main goal is that I want a `Styles.xaml` file which contains all styles to be used in the project. The styles in this file are not implicit. How can I make the `UserControl` see the XAML file? Should it not be a `StaticResouce`?

Comment: Everything you have should work. I just tested and it works fine for me. Is CustomControl an actual custom control or just a UserControl template that is named "CustomControl"?

Comment: `CustomControl` is an actual control. It's working for me now but I had to change `StaticResouce` to `DynamicResource`.